# Filling with White Color

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, style, filling

I am trying to fill multiple curves with different colors. For the purpose I have, I need to exclude some regions from shading. After searching, I realized that I can fill those regions with "White", which resembles the case that it is not shaded. So, this strategy seems perfect for my current project. However, it does not work for my case and it fills the entire region. Here is the simplified version of the code:

```
LogLogPlot[{x^2, x + 3}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {Bottom, White}, 2 -> Bottom }]
```

What I want is to fill between these two graphs without using the command

```
Filling->1->{2}
```

The reason for it is that the original problem is a little complicated and this way is the best way that comes to my mind. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: `plot1 = LogLogPlot[{x^2, x + 3}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Filling -> 2 -> {Bottom, Green}];
plot2 = LogLogPlot[{x^2, x + 3}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Filling -> 1 -> {Bottom, White}];
Show[plot1, plot2]`

Comment: Or more succinctly, `Show[LogLogPlot[{x^2, x + 3}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> #] & /@ {2 -> {Bottom, Green}, 1 -> {Bottom, White}}]`

Comment: It worked. Thank you all so much.